# Calling an async function every 5 seconds but it throws this error: 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp')'

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a weather app. I wanted to update the weather data every 5 seconds by calling the async function every 5 seconds using `setInterval()`. However, I get an error 400
[image]

```
const APIkey = 'api_key_value';
const apiURL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric'


//Default city set to New York
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.value = 'New York';

checkWeather();
let intervalID = setInterval(checkWeather, 5000)

const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    checkWeather();
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    intervalID = setInterval(checkWeather, 5000);
});

input.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        checkWeather();
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        intervalID = setInterval(checkWeather, 5000);
    }
});

async function checkWeather(){
    try {
        const response = await fetch(apiURL + `&q=${input.value}&appid=${APIkey}`)
        const data = await response.json();

        const temp = document.querySelector('.temp');
        temp.textContent = `${data.main.temp}°c`

        const city = document.querySelector('.city');
        city.textContent = data.name;

        const windspeed = document.querySelector('.windspeed');
        windspeed.textContent = `${data.wind.speed} km/h`

        const humidity = document.querySelector('.humid');
        humidity.textContent = `${data.main.humidity} %`

        const clouds = document.querySelector('.cloud');
        clouds.setAttribute('src',`images/${data.weather[0].main.toLowerCase()}.png`)

        input.value = '';
        
        console.log(data.main)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error occured:', error.message);
        const errorMsg = document.querySelector('.error-message');
        errorMsg.style.display = 'block'
    }
}
```

I tried to change the interval to a minute thinking that 5seconds is too quick but it still shows an error.

Comment: The error message tells you that "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp')", which means `data.main` is undefined since you are reading `temp` from `data.main`. That means `data` doesn't contain `main`. And this is cause by the API request fail . You might want to see what's wrong with your api call. Test it in postman.

Comment: And DO NOT post API keys in stackoverflow or any other places online. You should revoke your API key and create a new one ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I could not replicate your 400 error, I think you have a request limit (more info here: https://openweathermap.org/faq).

Take care with sharing your API KEY if you are using a paid version.

I think you have to handle this kind of error when you need a third API for you. Verify if fetch was successful and then continue with some error message.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-3#error400) 400 error occurrs because the required params are not passed to the API, and as per https://openweathermap.org/current you need to pass `lat` and `lon` to the API you are calling.